# Google Blogspot (post-share-buttons) social media removed

Tags: javascript, html, css, json, blogger

There is a share button on my blog I would like to remove all social media and leave only functional (link).

I can edit the HTML, but I can't find the code I need :-(

```
`https://pastebin.com/raw/6Ef8WigQ`
```

[My blog](https://test67534.blogspot.com/)

[I want to remove](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X6IWO.png)

Thx help me.

Comment: If I understand your question correctly, to remove the default social media buttons simply go to Layout -» Edit Blog Post and unselect that option. On the other part of your question, to add a functional link to the blog post, I think you have to edit the HTML but to proper place it, we need to know where you want to add it... probably you'll need to find '<b:includable id='post' var='post'>' and add it somewhere inside that includable... Your question is too vague to give you a more helful answer...

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

If what you want is something like:
https://skeleton08.blogspot.com/

Add the following to the CSS section or make those sections passive from the theme layout section.

CSS solution:

```css
/* your other CSS */

.post-share-buttons, .post-header, .snippet-thumbnail, .snippet-container, .post-bottom {
    display: none;
}
```

or if you want a simple template like: https://skeleton001.blogspot.com/

[image]

template code:
https://pastebin.pl/view/f12d550a